# how to make the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to true in one tabs of tablayout in android

Tags: android, tabs

I have  one TabActivity which contains some tabs ,which contains Activities each. In one of tabs which contains some activity has onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) it is not calling  when I  clicked on that tab. How can we make the method to call defaultly.

Can anybody help me in this issue, for any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to set or programmatically open a tab just use this

```
public TabHost mTabHost;
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(index_of_your_tab);
```

Comment: can you please tell me in detail ,I want to make that method to get focus defaultly  when the tab changed from any tab to that tab

Comment: Like for Example if you have three Tabs with index 0 1 and 2 from left, and currently you are in the Third Tab (index=2) and on the click even of a button you wish to bring your First Tab(i.e. index=0) you simply have to call `mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0)` on the `OnClick()` of the button Click